# what is action specific language(ASL)?

Tags: uml, xuml

What is action specific language and how to construct ASL statement based on the executable model(class diagram)?
I got the task from my university and they told me to write ASL statements of the executable model(for few features). I have already done with the executable model using xUML modeling standard but i am bit confused with ASL! Can you please help!

Comment: Asking your teacher might be the fastest way to find out what they want from you. Google points me to http://www.abstractsolutions.co.uk/XUML/asl.php and http://www.omg.org/spec/ALF/1.0.1

Comment: thanks for the great links. but i forget to tell you that its our task to do research on ASL and i was not able to find a single link related to ASL that's why i asked you. The links are perfect.

Comment: I used Google: `uml action specific language` (the words you have provided) and then I changed it to Google: `uml action specification language` as it seemed to be more "correct" according to the results that Google returned for the 1st query. Once you find the definition that matches your question you can post a [self-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) for future readers

Comment: thanks. i was searching through only "ACTION SPECIFIC LANGUAGE" thats why i was not getting the desired results".thanks for sharing. i will surely!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASL is Action Specification Language. This is an action language developed by a now defunct company named Kennedy-Carter. They developed a tool called iUML (intelligent UML). It was so named because it was an extension of the UML that supported the specification of executable, platform independent models. It is ultimately based on The Shlaer-Mellor Method which long predates UML and Kennedy-Carter. Another tool, Bridgepoint, now xtUML, introduced OAL, object action language (before ASL). Since then several other action languages have emerged. As of 2017 we have, in usage, OAL, ASL, Alf (Action Language Foundational) and Scrall (Starr's Concise Relational Action Language). Alf is the UML standard. Scrall was introduced in the book Models to Code, Apress 2017.  See UML.org for more about Alf and executableuml.org for more about Scrall.